# How to fix a loop to write multiple FASTA files from DNAStringSet in R?

Tags: r, loops, fasta, dna-sequence, writefile

I have this DNAStringSet (genomes) and need to put each genome as an individual FASTA file in a directory, but that they remain StringSets of length=1. The name of each file is concatenated in a vector (names), since they are too many I created this loop:

```
n <- seq_len(length(names))
for(i in 1:n){
  for(j in seq_len(length(names))){
  writeXStringSet(genomes[i],names[j])
  }
}
```

and returned this:

```
Warning message:
In 1:n : numerical expression has 95 elements: only the first used
```

I checked the results, the files where there with the right names but the sequence of all of them was the first one.
I changed the loop:

```
for(i in seq_len(length(genomes))){
  for(j in seq_len(length(names))){
  writeXStringSet(genomes[i],names[j])
  }
}
```

No error appeared, but now all files contain the last sequence of the StringSet.

I'm new using `Biostrings` package, I don't think I could use `lapply` or any of those since the object is not a list. Is there a way I could fix this so I can get all the files with their corresponding genome on it?

SAMPLE OF THE OBJECTS:

```
> genomes
DNAStringSet object of length 2:
    width seq                                          names               
[1] 47 TATAAAACACCCTCAATTCAAGGGTTTAATTTTTCACAATCATTAAA HP83
[2] 47 TAAAACACCCTCAATTCAAGGGTTTCATTTTTTAAAACTATTAAATA HPS49
[3] 47 AAAAACCTTGTTTTAGTCTTTTTTATAGATTTCATGTTCAAGTCTTC P49

>names <- c("HP83.fasta","HPS49.fasta","P49.fasta")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem lies in the assignment of your vector.

R is attempting to think about your first statement of:

```
n <- seq(x)
for (i in 1:n) { <whatever> }
```

as

```
for (i in 1:(1:n)) { <whatever> }
```

So R looks at that and essentially says "that doesn't make sense", runs a loop that looks like:

```
for (i in 1:1) { <whatever> }
```

and yells at you.

Your second problem is that you're making this a little more complicated than it needs to be. Because you have a nested loop, you're saving the first "i" with every "j", then the second, then the third, etc... and because "j" is specifying the file name to save to, what you see as a result is the last genome "i" being saved as every file name. writeXStringSet has append set to FALSE by default, so it is overwriting each previous iteration of the filename with a new one.

You really just need something that looks like:

```
for (m1 in seq_along(genomes)) {
  writeXStringSet(x = genomes[m1],
                  filepath = paste0("~/",
                                    m1,
                                    ".fasta"))
}
```

Or with your specific names

```
for (m1 in seq_along(genomes)) {
      writeXStringSet(x = genomes[m1],
                      filepath = names[m1])
}
```

In the future it is also helpful to give simple repeatable examples with your question. Such as "I have sequences that look like: ..."

```
<some snippet of code that generates simple exampel data>
```